# PyPy + PHP on a single webserver

Tags: php, python, apache, wsgi, pypy

I'm in the process of setting up a webserver from scratch, mainly for writing webapps with Python. On looking at alternatives to Apache+mod_wsgi, it appears that pypy plays very nicely indeed with pretty much everything I intend to use for my own apps. Not really having had a chance to play with PyPy properly, I feel this is a great opportunity to get to use it, since I don't need the server to be bulletproof.

However, there are some PHP apps that I would like to run on the webserver for administrative purposes (PHPPgAdmin, for example). Is there an elegant solution that allows me to use PyPy within a PHP-compatible webserver like Apache? Or am I going to have to run CherryPy/Paste or one of the other WSGI servers, with Apache and mod_wsgi on a separate port to provide administrative services?

Comment: One can quite happily run PHP and mod_wsgi on same Apache web server. Is there a actual specific issue or have you just not tried?

Comment: PyPy isn't compatible with mod_wsgi. My current setup runs mod_wsgi+apache+mod_php just fine :)

Comment: Whoops. I read that as PHP, not PyPy. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run your PyPy apps behind mod_proxy and serve static content with Apache (or even better use nginx). In addition to CherryPy, [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/configure.html) and [tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/) run great on PyPy.

Answer (score -1):

I know that mod_wsgi doesn't work with mod_php

I heavily advise you, running PHP and Python applications on CGI level.

PHP 5.x runs on CGI, for python there exists flup, that makes it possible to run WSGI Applications on CGI.

Tamer